# Can't connect to wireless on Ubuntu Server

Tags: wireless, networking, server, wpa-supplicant

I'm having some trouble connecting to a wireless network on Ubuntu Server 12.10. I have the driver installed with `ndiswrapper`, I can scan with `iwlist wlan0 scan`, and I'm trying to use `wpa_supplicant` to configure the interface. However, `iwconfig` is showing that I'm not connected to an access point.

---

`/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# Wireless interface
auto wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  wpa-driver ndiswrapper
  wpa-ssid "turkradio"
  wpa-ap-scan 2
  wpa-proto RSN
  wpa-pairwise CCMP
  wpa-group CCMP
  wpa-key-mgmt WPA-PSK
  wpa-psk KEY-FROM-WPA-PASSPHRASE
```

---

`/etc/wpa_supplicant.conf`

```
#ctrl_interface=/var/run/wpa_supplicant
ap_scan=2

network={
    ssid="turkradio"
    scan_ssid=1
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    group=TKIP
    pairwise=TKIP
    #psk="KEY"
    psk=ENCRYPTED_KEY
}
```

---

`ifconfig`

```
wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 08:86:3b:8a:d5:a5  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:0 (0.0 B)  TX bytes:0 (0.0 B)
```

---

`iwconfig`

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11g  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.442 GHz  Access Point: Not-Associated   
          Bit Rate:54 Mb/s   Tx-Power:20 dBm   Sensitivity=0/3  
          RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality:0  Signal level:0  Noise level:0
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

---

How can I correctly configure my interface?

Comment: Have you tried to run `wpa_supplicant` in a terminal`? (lieke `wpa_supplicant  -c /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf -i wlan0 -D ndiswrapper`)

Answer (score 3):

The following should work:

`/etc/network/interfaces` file:

```
auto wlan0
    iface wlan0 inet dhcp
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

`/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf` file:

```
network={
    ssid="turkradio"
    psk=ENCRYPTED_KEY
}
```

You get the encrypted key using the `wpa_passphrase` command:

```
wpa_passphrase turkradio key
```

Then to restart the networking(leave out the sudo if you are root):

```
sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using Wifi-Radar to see if it can scan your SSID and connect. You can install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install wifi-radar
```

It should be able to help you troubleshoot problems. You might have your key wrong or something else.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the output from `iwconfig` there is no SSID set.

I had the same problem as you and noticed the SSID not being set on my own machine. I set this using `iwconfig wlan0 essid "xxxxxxxxx"` and it immediately popped into action.

The SSID is set in the interfaces file but obviously it's not being read or retained. I now have to figure out how to configure it so that it 'sticks'. :-(